# The "data-pay-btn" BUTTON element does not have the specified CSS. How do I fix this

Tags: html, css

this is the question

Create a BUTTON as a sibling to the data-credit-card DIV. Set the BUTTON's class to mdc-button and give it a data-pay-btn attribute. It should have Pay & Checkout Now as its display text. After the user enters details of the card and clicks on this button, the app will strike-though the card numbers to indicate that they are in-valid.

```html
<button data-pay-btn class="mdc-button">Pay &amp; Checkout Now</button>
```

i expect to not get this error because I think my code is correct, but I keep getting this message

The "data-pay-btn" BUTTON element does not have the specified CSS

Comment: Try <button data-pay-btn=""  class="mdc-button">Pay &amp; Checkout Now</button>

Comment: What's giving you that error? I feel there's a lot of contextual information missing from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is referring to the myGradr challenge. Your CSS should be

```
[data-pay-btn] {
position: fixed;
width: 90%;
border: solid 1px;
bottom: 20px;
}
```

Place the button below the data-cart-info DIV